# Why do we press our nostrils inward when we blow our nose?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

Suppose my nose is runny and I want to blow mucus into a tissue.

**Scenario 1** (the typical scenario): I press my nostrils inward slightly with my hands, narrowing the passageway, and then blow forcefully.

**Scenario 2**: I simply blow forcefully without pressing my nostrils.

Assuming we use the same force in both scenarios, what is the physical reason that the first scenario feels more "satisfying", and expels so much more mucus than the second?

Comment: I think I read (or heard) somewhere that scenario 2 not a good idea as it pushes mucus up into your sinuses and it is better to close one nostril and lightly blow through the other.

Comment: I think it's something related to the equation of continuity. So, if we assume it enters the passage with a constant volume flow rate then narrowing the outlet (nostrils) will increase its speed with which it comes out. However, this is a good question +1.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I'd say because the pressure behind the mucus is increased - a thinner tube of air going alongside the mucus makes it more likely for air particles to transfer their outward momentum unto the mucus.

Much like electrons on a circuit board with resistors, the air will take the easier way out. Narrowing that easy way makes it harder, until it is more likely to move the mucus than go past it.